# Add new empty row at beginning in wijmo grid angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, wijmo5

I am trying to add a new empty row at the beginning of grid on external button click. Grid is showing perfectly fine.

```
<wj-flex-grid #flex 
    [itemsSource]="data" 
    [isReadOnly]="true" 
    [headersVisibility]="'Column'" 
    [selectionMode]="'ListBox'" 
    (selectionChanged)="gridSelectionChange($event, flex)" 
    (loadedRows)="onGridLoaded($event)">
</wj-flex-grid>
```

and data using `collectionView`:

```
this.data = new wjcCore.CollectionView(records);
```

Using `[allowAddNew] = 'true'`, It adds new row in bottom by default. 
But I want to add at beginning on button click.

**Updated:**

```
addNewRow(ctl) {
    this.data.addNew();
}
```

where `addNewRow` working fine but adding in **bottom**:

```
<a (click)="addNewRow(flex)">add new</a>
```

Please help how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To set the new row at top, wijmo grid provides a property `newRowAtTop`.

Modify your code like below:

```
<wj-flex-grid #flex 
    [newRowAtTop] = "true"
    [itemsSource]="data" 
    [isReadOnly]="true" 
    [headersVisibility]="'Column'" 
    [selectionMode]="'ListBox'" 
    (selectionChanged)="gridSelectionChange($event, flex)" 
    (loadedRows)="onGridLoaded($event)">
</wj-flex-grid>
```

Note the `[newRowAtTop] = "true"` part in above code.

Following description of `newRowAtTop` is copied from [this](http://wijmo.com/5/docs/topic/wijmo.grid.sheet.FlexSheet.Class.html#newRowAtTop) link:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the new row template
>   should be located at the top of the grid or at the bottom.
>
> If you set the newRowAtTop property to true, and you want the new row
>   template to remain visible at all times, set the frozenRows property
>   to one. This will freeze the new row template at the top so it won't
>   scroll off the view.
>
> The new row template will be displayed only if the allowAddNew
>   property is set to true and if the itemsSource object supports adding
>   new items.